# Read-Host in While loop with if statement

Tags: powershell

This should be really simple, but I cannot make it work. I'm new to the PowerShell so my mistake is probably obvious. I'm trying to ask a user for an input using a while loop, and prompting the user to try again if what was entered was not numeric. In bash it would look like this:

```
while read -p "What is the first number? " first; do
if [[ $first = *[[:digit:]]* ]]; then
break   # if $first is numeric, break loop
else
echo "$first is not numeric. Enter a numeric value. "
fi
done
```

Here's what I have for the PS:

```
While ($first = (Read-Host "What is the first number?") -as [double]) {
if ($first -eq $null) { Write-Host "Please enter a numeric value." }
else { break }
}
```

In the example above, I can break the loop fine when a number is entered, but I can't see the `Write-Host` statement if I type a string.

Comment: the `while` test is run before the loop is run. that means your `if` test will prevent the "then" result from _ever_ running. [*grin*]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the `While` line:

```
While ($first = (Read-Host "What is the first number?") -as [double])
```

This will only enter/continue the loop body when the input is already a double, because it rolls up the cast to `double` as part of the loop condition. You want to enter the loop body on *any* input, and only check if it's a double afterwards. At least, that's what the bash code does:

```
While ($first = (Read-Host "What is the first number?")) {
    if ( ($first -as [double]) -eq $null) { Write-Host "Please enter a numeric value." }
    else { break }
}
```

Or you could continue using the cast as part of the condition by negating the whole expression, and thus avoid the need for the awkward `break`:

```
While (-not ($first = (Read-Host "What is the first number?") -as [double])) {
    Write-Host "Please enter a numeric value." 
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I think it should be `[double]` and not `double` in the first solution though.

Comment: @HubertLéveilléGauvin Yes, that was a copy/pasta error.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this to keep prompting for a valid number input as you are looking for.

```
Do {
    "Please enter a numeric value." | Out-Host
    $first = (Read-Host "What is the first number?") -as [double]
} While($null -eq $first)
```